# JWT - How to pass the PrivateKey to "SigningCredentials" to build SecurityTokenDescriptior?

Tags: c#, jwt

I am on a way to create JWT token using c#.NET. I have my own private key as xml. I need to pass that as one of parameter to the function signingCredentials. My code looks as below:

```
            var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(List),
                Audience = "Audi",
                Issuer = "Issr",
                Expires = 5,
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Key), Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
            };
```

Like to know how to pass the privatekey for SigningCredentials.

I have my own private key as xml file between the tags RSAKeyValue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

try to use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey (byte[] key) :

```
new SigningCredentials(new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.Commons.SECRET_KEY)), Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had a certificate with private key - PKCS#12 then it would be [easy](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/c5059dae1f97438421ab9f62de3ff9c75255fd52/test/IdentityServer.UnitTests/Common/TestCert.cs)

```
new SigningCredentials(new X509SecurityKey(cert), "RS256");
```

So make a certificate.

Comment: I don't have any certificates. i have only the private key.

Answer (score 1):

1. We make a symmetric security key and assign your "secret-key"
   to it.
2. Then we make a SigningCredentials instance and pass the key we made and the algorithm we want to use
3. Then we just assign our credentials to the SigningCredentials property in the SecurityTokenDescriptor

*Example code below*

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
                .GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
    
var tokenDescrpitor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your way, you can create one more method `GetSigningCredentials()`:

```
 private SigningCredentials GetSigningCredentials()
    {
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SECRETKEY"));
        var secret = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);

        return new SigningCredentials(secret, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    }
```

…and you will have `SigningCredentials = GetSigningCredentials();`